# QGIS Grid size accuracy

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector-grid, dimensions

I am using QGIS.

I have been using "research tools/create grid" during my process to generate XY coordinates for field research.  Using opentopomap for map layer.  Using shapefiles.

In the grid parameter selection/horizontal/vertical spacing I am offered units meters, providing CRS is ESPG:3857 pseudo mercator.  (Other CRS might offer degrees units.)

First try, I set horizontal and vertical spacing to 25m.  Generated the grid.  Measured the grid cells using the measure tool from the toolbar, which told me the cells are approximately 19m x 19m.

I found that setting the horizontal/vertical spacing to 27m would yield me a grid dimension of approximately 20m, according to the measure tool from the toolbar.  After extracting XY coordinates from this file, and uploading to a GPS unit, some field testing shows me that the on the ground measurement is fairly accurate.  That is, approximately 20m per side.

Why is the parameter field off by this amount?

Comment: ESPG:3857 pseudo mercator is designed for web mapping tiles, it is very inaccurate for measurements.  Choose a projected coordinate system that suits your area of interest.

Comment: When using the measure tool from the toolbar, always set measurement to ellipsoidal, **not** cartesian. Ellipsoidal measurements are more accurate.